# Cannot scrape this specific div class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am curious why I cannot get the div-elements with this class as follows (which worked before but on different sites). Maybe it is an issue with this site?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.docmorris.de/produkte/abnehmen"
page=requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features="lxml")
divs=soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class": "l-product mod-standard product 
list-item ff-slider"})
print(divs)
```

prints an empty array. I want all div elements with class 'l-product mod-standard product list-item ff-slider'

Comment: There is a new line char on you class attribute and i guess that is why it is not matching. I would suggest to make it a single line rather than 2 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a single class of the multi-value and that will be less fragile. Also, remove headers.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.docmorris.de/produkte/abnehmen"
page = requests.get(url)  
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features="lxml")
divs = soup.select('.l-product')
print(divs)
```

The multi-valued (more fragile) would be:

```
divs = soup.select('.l-product.mod-standard.product.list-item.ff-slider')
```

Or (as in comments - ensure on one line) :

```
divs = soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class": "l-product mod-standard product list-item ff-slider"})
```

Comment: But if you look at the source code, you see no dots in the class name?! Why do you use dots. Why should '.l-product' work?

Comment: The top version is selecting by css. In css selectors the dot is a class selector. You join multi-valued classes with the dots and no spaces. You can match on an item with multi-values by any of its single values. The trick is to see if there is one of those classes which still uniquely identifies the elements of interest (and not other elements).

Comment: both comments above are not working with soup.select('.l-product') eg.

Comment: have you tried it? Also my way and the class name in just one line (which was in one line before too) does not work

Comment: I test all my code unless I state otherwise. It returns a list of the divs with that class. What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks it works I did a stupid mistake and had a mispelling my url! Sorry for that